# Multiple functions with optional arguments causes the arguments to get lost on the stack

Tags: python

The following code:

```py
def func_3(some_number, other_number=1):
    print("func_3 " + str(other_number))
    return other_number
    
def func_2(some_number, other_number=1):
    print("func_2 " + str(other_number))
    return func_3(some_number, other_number=1)

def func_1(some_number, other_number=1):
    print("func_1 " + str(other_number))
    return func_2(some_number, other_number=1)

def func_0(some_number, other_number=1):
    print("func_0 " + str(other_number))
    return func_1(some_number, other_number=1)

func_0(123456, 2)
```

will generate the following output:

```
func_0 2
func_1 1
func_2 1
func_3 1
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: Nothing is getting lost. You're calling `func_1`, `func_2`, and `func_3` with `other_number=1`, and it's printing out `1`, i.e. the value of `other_number`. It's right there in your code. I don't understand where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: Call the inner functions with `other_number` not `other_number=1`.  You're not passing on the number received by the function, you are calling the inner function with a specific keyword argument of 1.

Answer (score 3):

Besides `func_0`, you're explicitly passing in 1 for the `other_number` parameter. If you want to pass in 2, rather than 1, change the return statements so that they explicitly pass in `other_number` as a parameter.

For example, use:

```py
return func_1(some_number, other_number=other_number)
```

rather than:

```py
return func_1(some_number, other_number=1)
```

Comment: Yes, this was caused by my misunderstanding of Python syntax. Basically I confused the function signature with the syntax in the call. Silly mistakes sometimes happen to experienced programmers!  Thanks!